# Extract the substrings under certain conditions

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have the following string in Excel: `C37S25FF0000TD`.
In 7 different cells, I need to extract 7 substring according to these directions:

- The first cell must contain the letters up to the first number. In this case it must contain only `C`.
- The second cell must contain the first number that appears (this number can also have more than two digits). In this case it must contain only `37`.
- The third cell must contain the following letters, up to the next number. In this case only `S`.
- The fourth cell must contain the next two digits (they are always two digits). In this case `25`.
- The fifth cell must contain the next 6 characters. In this case `FF0000`.
- The sixth cell must contain the next character. In this case `T`.
- The seventh cell must contain the last character. In this case `D`.

Can someone help me? Since substrings can have variable length I don't know how to use the function `MID()` correctly. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Show your sample data with desired output?

Comment: Check out the functions left(), right(), mid(), len(), find(), trim(). Lits of examples of their use on here and Excel has them in the help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

***Edited to allow for leading zero's in second substring***

Here is a set of formulas that take into account the fact that some of the substrings may be of varying length.

Some of the formulas use functions only found in Office 365. However, substitutes for earlier versions are also available:

```
Letters up to first number: = LEFT(A1,MIN(FIND({0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9},A1&"0123456789"))-1)

Next first full number (variable number of digits: 
    =LET(s,MID(A1,LEN(B1)+1,LEN(A1)),
       arr, MID(s,SEQUENCE(LEN(s)),1),
       len, MATCH(TRUE,ISERR(-arr),0),
       LEFT(s,len-1))

Subsequent letter(s): 
        =LET(s,MID(A1,SUM(LEN(B1:B2))+1,LEN(A1)),
           pos,MIN(FIND({0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9},s&"0123456789")),
           LEFT(s,pos-1))

Next two characters: =MID(A1,SUM(LEN(B1:B3))+1,2)

For the subsequent substrings, we can count from the right:
   First 6 of the last 8 characters: =MID(A1,LEN(A1)-7,6)

    Penultimate character: =MID(A1,LEN(A1)-1,1)

    Last character:  =RIGHT(A1)
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Reminded me of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69260283/9758194) UDF that can come in handy if you'd change the pattern:

```
Function GetData(inp As String, grp As Long) As String

With CreateObject("VBScript.RegExp")
    .Pattern = "^([A-Z]+)(\d+)([A-Z]+)(\d\d)(.{6})(.)(.)$"
    If .Test(inp) Then
        GetData = .Execute(inp)(0).Submatches(grp - 1)
    Else
        GetData = "No Data Found"
    End If
End With

End Function
```

[Here](https://regex101.com/r/xgagud/1) is an online demo. It would match:

- `^` - Start-line anchor;
- `([A-Z]+)` - A 1st capture group to match 1+ uppercase alpha-chars;
- `(\d+)` - A 2nd capture group to match 1+ digits;
- `([A-Z]+)` - A 3rd group identical to 1st;
- `(\d\d)` - A 4th group matching exactly two digits;
- `(.{6})` - A 5th group matching exactly 6 characters other than newline;
- `(.)` - A 6th group capturing the 2nd to last character;
- `(.)` - A final 7th group matching the last character;
- `$` - End-line anchor.

Call through `=GetData(A1,1)` where the 2nd parameter can be 1-7.

---

Also thought it's fun to see how to mimic this with a single formula:

[image]

Formula in `B1`:

```
=LET(A,A1,B,LEFT(A,LEN(A)-8),C,TEXTSPLIT(B,SEQUENCE(10,,0),,1),D,TEXTSPLIT(B,C,,1),E,MID(RIGHT(A,8),{1,7,8},{6,1,1}),HSTACK(TOROW(VSTACK(C,D),,1),E))
```

Answer (score 0):

So, based on the single example you gave and making no assumptions about changing positions:

[image]

You can edit to deal with any of the numbers that may contain extra digits etc by expanding on the technique using len() and find() as necessary.